# array.splice unexpected behavior with negative values index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I noticed [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Syntax) mentioned in the description of ***start Parameter*** :

- Index at which to start changing the array **(with origin 0)**
- If negative , will begin that many elements from the end of the array  **(with origin -1)**

This description working very good for me on **removing** elements for me :

Removing **1st** element :

```js
let foo = ["a", "b", "c"];
foo.splice(0,1) // "a" removed
console.log(foo);//["b", "c"]
```

Removing **last** element :

```js
let foo = ["a", "b", "c"];
foo.splice(-1,1) // "c" removed
console.log(foo);//["a", "b"]
```

**Now let's Try add elements**

add element at **1st**  :

```js
let foo = ["a", "b", "c"];
foo.splice(0,0,"x") // "x" added to 1st
console.log(foo);//["x", "a", "b", "c"]
```

**add element to the last** :

```js
let foo = ["a", "b", "c"];
foo.splice(-1,0,"x") 
// I expected to added "x" as a last element
// but instead it shows ["a", "b", "x", "c"]
console.log(foo);
```

can anyone explain why ?

the last case shows  ["a", "b", **"x"** , "c"]

if you wanna remove the same element from it's position we should remove it from index of -2 not -1 :

```js
let foo = ["a", "b", "c"];
foo.splice(-1,0,"x")
console.log(foo);
//["a", "b", "x", "c"]
foo.splice(-2,1)
console.log(foo);
```

Thanks...

Comment: *"-n is the index of the nth last element and is therefore equivalent to the index of array.length - n*"  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Syntax

Comment: Seems entirely consistent…!? `0` removes “a” and *inserts before “a”*. `-1` removes “c” and *inserts before “c”*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initially lets consider foo as `["a", "b", "c"]` and `foo.length` is 3.

So when you are adding the element using `foo.splice(-1,0,"x")`, the index is calculated as `foo.length - 1` which is 2.

So the new element is inserted at the index 2:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
  0    1    2
            ^
            |__________"x" added here
```

So the new array becomes `["a", "b", "x", "c"]` as "x" is inserted at index 2 and "c" is shifted by one index.

When you remove the element using `foo.splice(-2,0)`, the index at which it is removed `foo.length - 2` which is 2:

```
["a", "b", "x", "c"]
  0    1    2    3
            ^
            |__________ "x" is removed
```

And the array becomes `["a", "b", "c"]`.

Answer (score 0):

[Splice function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) accepts three parameters,

- `start`: Index from where to change the array.
- `deleteCount`: Number of elements to remove.
- `items(varargs)`: Elements to add, beginning from `start` index.

```js
let foo = ["a", "b", "c"];
foo.splice(-1,0,"x") 
// I expected to added "x" as a last element
// but instead it shows ["a", "b", "x", "c"]
console.log(foo);
```

In the above code snippet, you are passing `start` as -1, so it's get added on last index (which is calculated as `arr.length - 1`) and `deleteCount` as 0 so no elements are **deleted** instead they are moved to right by one index.