# How push element to an array using Array.prototype.splice() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know we can push/append a new element to an array using `Array.prototype.push()`, however i was thinking if i can achieve same behaviour using `Array.prototype.splice()`?

I tried to give index `-1` but it doesn't seem to give me expected result and i found correspond Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55321289/12733140):

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b']
arr.splice(-1, 0, 'c')

console.log(arr) // ['a', 'c', 'b']
```

Therefore i was wondering if i could simulate `Array.prototype.push()` using `Array.prototype.splice()` API?

Comment: have you read the [docs on Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) yet?

Comment: @DanO I have, but i might missed something, could you give me some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr.splice(arr.length, 0, 'c')
```

Comment: OK great, I just realized i just kept thinking about how to solve this problem using negative index, fell into the trap i created by myself.